# Woocommerce, set shipping class based on cart item quantity

Tags: php, woocommerce

Hi im trying to set different shipping classes in the cart dependent on how many items there are in the cart. I have tried to make this work by adding the following to functions.php.

```php
//Set shipping class based on item quantity
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'shipping_class_and_item_quantity'); 
function shipping_class_and_item_quantity( $cart ) {

    $shipping_class_one = '1-6-flaskor';
    $shipping_class_two = '7-12-flaskor';

    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $product = $cart_item['data'];

        if( $cart_item['quantity'] >= 6 ) {
            $product->get_shipping_class() == $shipping_class_one;
        }else if( $cart_item['quantity'] >= 12 ){
            $product->get_shipping_class() == $shipping_class_two;
        }
    }
}
```

found something similar online, which I've been trying to reverse engineer, but it doesn't seem to work, most likely due to my limited php skills. Very thankful for any help.

Comment: Hey can I ask what you're trying to achieve? Shipping classes in woocommerce are set at the product level.
I would recommend changing the shipping method directly based on how many products are in the cart if that's what your trying to do? 
Or manipulate the price directly for a single shipping condition? 
Please explain your goal and I can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-read your question. Would something like this work?

```
function custom_shipping_cost_tiers( $cost, $method ) {
    $methodlabel = 'Enter the name of your method here' ie 'Flat Rate';

    if ($method->get_label() == $methodlabel) {
        $cart_item_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();

        if ( $cart_item_count >= 6) {
            $cost = *SET FEE HERE*;
        }
        else if ( $cart_item_count >= 12){
            $cost = *SET FEE HERE*;
        }
    return $cost;
    }
 }

add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_rate_cost', 'custom_shipping_cost_tiers', 10, 2 );
```

This should do what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi William, thanks for your help, this works and solves most of my problem! However, this solution puts the specified fee on all of the shipping methods, do you have an idea of how I could implement a check so that the rate will only be applied to a certain shipping method?

Comment: Hey edited my code. This should do the trick! What ever you have called you method needs to go in the $methodlabel variable.

Comment: Thank you William, that did the trick! I really appreciate the help, thank you!

Comment: Please can you mark the answer as correct! Thanks :)